# Rails 3 routing with resources under an optional scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-routes, custom-routes

I have [setup my versioned API](http://www.starkiller.net/2011/03/17/versioned-api-1/) like this with only a small tweak for backwards compatibility. In my routes I have:

```
scope '(api(/:version))', :module => :api, :version => /v\d+?/ do
    …
    scope '(categories/:category_id)', :category_id => /\d+/ do
        …
        resources :sounds
        …
    end
end
```

with the successful goal already reached of having the following URL's reach the same place

```
/api/v1/categories/1/sounds/2
/api/categories/1/sounds/2
/categories/1/sounds/2
/sounds/2
```

My directory structure is like this:

[image]

The problem I am seeing is in my link generations in my views. For example, on the sound show page I have a `button_to` to delete the sound

```
<%= button_to 'Delete', @sound, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Which generates the following url in the form `action`:

```
"/api/sounds/1371?version=1371"
```

And furthermore, the `delete` method is not working, instead it is being sent as a `POST`

The interesting parts of `rake routes` are:

```
                     sounds GET    (/api(/:version))(/categories/:category_id)/sounds(.:format)                               {:controller=>"api/sounds", :version=>/v\d+?/, :action=>"index", :category_id=>/\d+/}
                            POST   (/api(/:version))(/categories/:category_id)/sounds(.:format)                               {:controller=>"api/sounds", :version=>/v\d+?/, :action=>"create", :category_id=>/\d+/}
                  new_sound GET    (/api(/:version))(/categories/:category_id)/sounds/new(.:format)                           {:controller=>"api/sounds", :version=>/v\d+?/, :action=>"new", :category_id=>/\d+/}
                 edit_sound GET    (/api(/:version))(/categories/:category_id)/sounds/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:controller=>"api/sounds", :version=>/v\d+?/, :action=>"edit", :category_id=>/\d+/}
                      sound GET    (/api(/:version))(/categories/:category_id)/sounds/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"api/sounds", :version=>/v\d+?/, :action=>"show", :category_id=>/\d+/}
                            PUT    (/api(/:version))(/categories/:category_id)/sounds/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"api/sounds", :version=>/v\d+?/, :action=>"update", :category_id=>/\d+/}
                            DELETE (/api(/:version))(/categories/:category_id)/sounds/:id(.:format)                           {:controller=>"api/sounds", :version=>/v\d+?/, :action=>"destroy", :category_id=>/\d+/}
```

and the server logs show:

```
Started POST "/api/sounds/1371?version=1371" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri May 06 23:28:27 -0400 2011
  Processing by Api::SoundsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"W+QlCKjONG5i/buIgLqsrm3IHi5gdQVzFGYGREpmWYs=", "id"=>"1371", "version"=>371}
```

I am using JQuery as my UJS and have the most recent version of rails.js for JQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- must be >= 1.4.4 for the rails 3 link js to work—> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ujs/src/rails.js?1304736923" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I know this is `tl;dr` but my question is: "**What do I need to put in my button_to link_to and other view tags to make the url helpers generate the correct path for my setup?**" I have tried just about every combination I can think of but can never get them to end up in the right place.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or Prototype as a JavaScript framework. And if so is it included in the page that's giving you problems? Also, are you sure your rails.js file matches your JavaScript framework? I would guess that the problem is somewhere in the JavaScript. But it's also strange that the show action is handling the POST request.

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.4.4, and the most recent rails.js for jquery as well. I updated my question to show the JS in head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the solution was an easy one. I had two mistakes here that caused the wrong route to generate and the url to append params.

1. above the `resources :sounds` route, I mistakenly had this line:

   ```
   match '/sounds/:id(/:format)' => 'sounds#show'
   ```

   I have this line so that `sounds/123/xml` can be page cached. This caused all the routing to `show` and I realized the mistake was that I had the `:format` in parens, and the match should be a `get`. Now it reads:

   ```
   get '/sounds/:id/:format' => 'sounds#show'
   ```
2. Next, in the `button_to` link, I was placing the `@sound` object as my second param. Rails was trying to be intelligent an extrapolate the right url from this, but was failing with the optional api `:version` param. Changing it to

   ```
   sound_path(:id => @sound.id)
   ```

   worked like a charm.