# Rails routes, has_many and optional nested resource sanity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I know how to setup nested resources in the routes files already… the question is for how to do it optionally with the same payload, and with fewer lines.

Lets say I have a `BlogSite`. BlogSite has many `Posts`, but it also has many `Authors` and many `Dates`. (this might not be the best example, but bear with me).

To do CRUD on a `Post`, I want to be able to use

```
/blog_sites/1/author/2/date/3/posts #all posts on site 1 from author 2 on date 3
/blog_sites/1/author/2/posts        #all posts on site 1 from author 2
/blog_sites/1/date/3/posts          #all posts on site 1 on date 3
/blog_sites/1/posts                 #all posts on site 1
/author/2/date/3/posts              #all posts from author 2 on date 3
/author/2/posts                     #all posts from author 2
/date/3/posts                       #all posts from date 3
/posts                              #all posts
```

Such that any of the filtering parameters can be optional in the URL. I know that you can use something like

```
get (/blog_sites/:blog_id)(/author/:author_id)(/date/:date_id)/posts => "posts#index"
```

but I don't want to lose all the CRUD benefits of using nested resource routing. Currently I have to duplicate much of the routing to make it work, and am looking for a better way to do this:

```
resources :blog_sites do
    resources :authors do
        resources :dates do
            resources :posts
        end
        resources :posts
    end
    resources :dates do
        resources :posts
    end
    resources :posts
end
```

… and so on. It can get pretty unmanageable petty quickly.

**How can I maintain the optional param urls whilst keeping routes.rb `DRY` and sane?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use scope and resources together.  [Rails 3 routing with resources under an optional scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918938/rails-3-routing-with-resources-under-an-optional-scope)

```
scope 'blog_sites/:blog_id)(/author/:author_id)(/date/:date_id)' do 
    resources :posts
end
```

Comment: This was exactly how I ended up solving it, though I used nested scopes so I could specify the conditions all of the params cleanly on each line, next to its resource